# How to understand the output of using gsub on a data.frame

Tags: r

Can you use `gsub` on a data.frame?

```
dat="1   1W   16   2W   16
2    1   16   2W    W
3   1W   16   16    0
4    4   64   64    0"      
data=read.table(text=dat,header=F)
gsub("W",3,data)
```

Why we get an output such as below:

```
[1] "1:4"               "c(2, 1, 2, 3)"     "c(16, 16, 16, 64)" "c(2, 2, 1, 3)"     "c(2, 3, 1, 1)"   .
```

It is hard to understand.

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ V1: int  1 2 3 4
 $ V2: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","1W","4": 2 1 2 3
 $ V3: int  16 16 16 64
 $ V4: Factor w/ 3 levels "16","2W","64": 2 2 1 3
 $ V5: Factor w/ 3 levels "0","16","W": 2 3 1 1
```

What is the meaning of the **2 1 2 3 ** in  `V2: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","1W","4": 2 1 2 3`?

Comment: Yet I answered your previous question *showing* you how to do this with `lapply`.

Comment: you need either `sapply` or `lapply` to loop over each column of your data.frame: `as.data.frame(sapply(data,function(x) gsub("W",3,x)))`

Comment: @SimonO101, me too, on another question from today....

Comment: @Jilber, there are better ways to do this than your proposal. `data[] <- lapply(data, function(x) gsub("W", 3, x))`, for example.

Comment: Yes, you're right @AnandaMahto, I forgot how to use `[` in this context. Thanks for pointing that out  ;)

Comment: See, also, `gsub("W",3,as.matrix(data))`. Of course, then you have to convert it back to `data.frame` and `sapply` the right `class` to each column. Also, use `unclass(data)` to see that a `data.frame` is not what it looks like and why `(l/s)apply` was proposed above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is the same as `as.character(data)`.

Since the letter `W` never appears in any of these strings, `gsub` has no effect, other than the conversion to character.

As discussed in the comments, `as.character` has quirky behaviour on data frames.  It calls `as.vector(x, "character")`, which needs to condense each column to a single value, and chooses to return the code needed to recreate the column, ignoring attributes.  For factor columns this means that you get the integer levels, not the string values, which is why `W` never appears.

Comment: Should be noted that as `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` was not specified the representation returned is the factor levels rather than the values themselves (this threw me for a minute).

Comment: Sine the letter W never appears in any of these strings,data[1,2] contain letter  W  .

Comment: @it_is_a_literature try `read.table( text = dat , header = FALSE , stringsAsFactors = FALSE )`. R is reading your columns which are supposed to be `character` vectors and and is converting them to `factors` so it returns the factor level codes.

Comment: what is the meaning of the *2 1 2 3 * in V2: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","1W","4": 2 1 2 3?

Comment: the first four elements of `V2` correspond to factor levels 2,1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

You need to `apply` through each value in your data frame:

```
apply(data, 1:2, function(x) gsub("W", 3, x))
#      V1  V2   V3   V4   V5  
# [1,] "1" "13" "16" "23" "16"
# [2,] "2" "1"  "16" "23" "3" 
# [3,] "3" "13" "16" "16" "0" 
# [4,] "4" "4"  "64" "64" "0"
```

@Richie Cotton's comments explain why you need to do it this way.